# Does a .NET Framework 4.7.1 compiled application run with .NET Framework 4.7.0?

Tags: c#, .net

If I compile an application using .NET Framework 4.7.1, will this application run on a computer where only .NET Framework 4.7.0 is installed? Or are there any issues to be expected?

Comment: it should. try it.

Comment: It is quite impossible to answer. This depends on what changes there are between .NET 4.7.0 and 4.7.1, and whether your application is relying on any of those changes. In the general sense this question is impossible to answer and only a detailed analysis of what you've used of .NET 4.7.x features can tell you whether it will actually run. Your best option is probably just to try it and see what happens, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: You could check this page - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/17/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-1/ - if your application is using any of the new features listed there it's a safe bet it won't run out of the box on 4.7.0.

Comment: This may help to summarize the expected issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.7-4.7.1

Comment: I guess i do understand (more or less). If i just change the framework version from 4.7.0 to 4.7.1 without any code modification it will most likely run on a computer with only 4.7.0 installed. But as soon as i start using any new features, it may break.

Answer (score 3):

By default, an application compiled against .NET 4.7.1 will not run on a computer with only .NET 4.7.0 installed. Reason for this is the app.config which contains an explicit set sku:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

If this app.config is edited or deleted, the .NET 4.7.1 compiled application will run on a system with only .NET 4.7.0 (or even 4.5) installed, but there will be runtime errors if something is not as expected.